# SwiftyJson doesn't work?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

[image]

I'm trying to get information off a website that I created myself, where I need to read a JSON object to import it's data into my iOS App (written in Swift). I can only find very few tutorials on how to do that, and most of which are using a SWIFTYJson Library (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). The problem is when I use the Library the actual Library code itself seems to be having some errors, maybe due to the recent updates in Xcode. Even the example from the tutorial doesn't work.

Has anyone different apporaches to solve this problem without using SwiftyJson?

Thanks

This is the actual SwiftyJson file that i donwloaded. This is now in his own example where the code seems to be having some errors.

Comment: What do you need help with? Get the JSON from the server or parsing the resulting JSON?

Comment: Can you post some example code or post the errors you are getting?

Comment: @Anchor i posted the image, as you can see there are coding errors in the file that i downloaded. i don't really have enough knowledge to solve the coding issues myself and i'm now looking for another way to get information off a website that has a json file

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: Currently using 6.3 @SebastianOsiński do you think i need to new one?

Comment: Yes. This is the cause you have problems with SwiftyJSON. You downloaded the newest version of the library which was written to use with Swift 2.1, and Xcode 6.3 is bundled with Swift 1.2 if I recall correctly. Use the newest Xcode available. Now you are using not only the outdated IDE but also outdated version of Swift.

Comment: So the errors should be gone with the newest version of xcode istelf.. i'll download it then and hopefully it'll work then :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in comment, you use Xcode 6.3 and this is the cause SwiftyJSON isn't working. You've downloaded the newest version of the library, which is compatible with Swift 2.1 and Xcode 6.3 is bundled with Swift 1.2 if I recall correctly. You should always use the newest version of the Xcode available (not counting beta releases). Version of Xcode also affects version of Swift you have. As Swift is young language, it faces lots of changes between versions which triggers changes in frameworks written in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The first error which I can see "No type named Indexable..." seems to be [reported in the SwiftyJSON project few months ago](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/305) and the solution to it is to use Xcode 7 for building.

I can also see that you use iOS SDK 8.3, which probably could be updated to 9.2 and fix the problem. If you use Xcode 6, try updating to Xcode 7 and the errors will probably be fixed. Also I don't see any reason to use old SDK version if a new one is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try import SwiftyJSON file as below without project.
[image]

If you want to use like your version:

Try to create a new `swift` file and import this swiftyJSON `version` manually. (not the latest) This should work with `xcode 7.2` and `Swift 2` and `deployment target 8.0.`

https://gist.github.com/fatihyildizhan/450822246e8deb14099c

> Requirements
>   iOS 7.0+ / Mac OS X 10.9+, 
>   Xcode 7

Answer (score -3):

Don't forget to import `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`.

```
 // This is Alamofire Request
  func LoginWithAPI(completion : (String) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "your_api_url", parameters: ["username":"bodrum", "password":"yalikavak"], encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON)
      .validate()
      .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
          // Parse your result to JSON object first.
          // JSON is SwiftyJSON object.
          let jsonResponse = JSON(data: response.data!)
          let result = jsonResponse["result"].stringValue
          completion(result)
        case .Failure(let error):
          completion(error.description)
        }
    }
  }
```

if you want to add any `header`, use this line:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "your_api_url", parameters: ["username":"bodrum", "password":"yalikavak"], encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON,
  headers: ["header_key": "header_value"])
```

Comment: well i don't really need to import the swiftyjson because i actually put the file within my project. the problem is that the library itself seems to have errors. do you know of any other ways to solve this?